# How to set IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE in cmake?

Tags: cmake

By default 32-bit process can use up to 2GB address space (Windows 10 x64). In Visual Studio 2019 it can be change in the project properties: linker/settings. How to set IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag in cmake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` variables for that, e.g.

```
if (MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /LARGEADDRESSAWARE")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} /LARGEADDRESSAWARE")
endif()
```

Another possibility (modern CMake style) is to set the property of the target, i.e.

```
if (MSVC)
    set_target_properties(MyTargetName PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/LARGEADDRESSAWARE")
endif()
```

Comment: Is IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag MSVC specific ?

Comment: It is a special linker flag for the Microsoft linker, so yes it is MSVC specific.

Comment: @Irbis the GCC equivalent is spelled `-Wl,--large-address-aware`, which tells it to pass `--large-address-aware` to the linker. Looks like Clang's `lld` linker may support the same flag.